# cannot get value from angularJS value service

Tags: angularjs, events, event-handling

I study the book "AngularJS by Example" and I am in the part about event handling. (pp. 145-147)

In a file `workout.js`, that contains  a controller is the emiter

`$scope.$emit(appEvents.workout.exerciseStarted,exercisePlan.details);`

and then outside of the controller I set a value service like

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').value("appEvents", {
    workout: { exerciseStarted: "event:workout:exerciseStarted" }
});
```

In another file ,`services.js`, that contains my service, there is the event handler `$rootScope.$on(appEvents.workout.exerciseStarted, function (e,args) {`

Outside the service factory function I set the same value service like

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').value("appEvents", {
    workout: { exerciseStarted: "event:workout:exerciseStarted" }
});
```

I run this and get

`ReferenceError: appEvents is not defined` and points to the line `$rootScope.$on(appEvents.workout.exerciseStarted, function (e,args) {` of the `services.js` file. I am confused. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you have forget to inject `appEvents ` dependency

Comment: @PankajParkar Inject it where exactly? In the controller or the service?

Comment: @PankajParkar I had to inject it in the controller and also in my filter , to work. But here is a question. Since this is a value service, as the book says,  shouldn't I also inject `value` or something like that? As I did with `location`?

Comment: A service is a service is a service. Whether you define it with constant(), value() service() or factory() doesn't matter. To use it, you inject it. Defining the same appEvents service twice is also completely useless.

Comment: @JBNizet Ooops yes, I double-defined it. Thanks